# How to change accels in GNOME 3.10?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, evolution

Up to GNOME 3.8 you could easily change your keyboard shortcuts inside an application with dconf, but that option is deprecated now. (I've read an entry on a mailing list about that.)
Unfortunately, I could not find any other option to adapt the shortcuts to my needs for e.g. Evolution. I'd like to change the "send mail" command from `Ctrl+Enter` to `Alt+S`. I have browsed through the `.config/evolution` directory and found the according `accels` file.

I have changed the gtk-accel for send mail (`gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mailto/send-message"`) to `<Primary><Shift>1` for testing purpose and uncommented the line. However, changes applied to that file do not change anything, since Evolution seems to overwrite that file on startup.

How could I alter the keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just make sure Evolution is closed when you edit and save the ~/.config/evolution/accels file.

Comment: Make sure to remove the semicolon at the beginning of the line if there is one, as Evolution overwrites those (even if changes are done when Evo is closed).